# Java/Libgdx - How can I draw multiple circles without blinking effect?

Tags: java, libgdx, 2d

Maybe my title doesn't fit very well but I will try to clearly explain.

In fact, I'm currently working on a little project using Libgdx. At the moment, the goal of this project is to be able to randomly display several circles on my screen.

I correctly displayed these circles on the screen but they are blinking.

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {

    renderer.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
    if(!mapIsCreated)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int x, y;
        for(int i=0;i<200;i++)
        {
            x = rand.nextInt(Gdx.graphics.getWidth());
            y = rand.nextInt(Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

            renderer.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            renderer.circle(x, y, 5);
            renderer.setColor(Color.GRAY);
            renderer.circle(x, y, 3);
        }
        mapIsCreated = true;
    }
    renderer.end();
}
```

Are there any solutions to definitively fix them on the background without blinking/reloading effects ?

If more details are needed, please let me know.

Comment: Create them one time in the create() method and store them in an array. Read them from the array in the render method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never seem to clear your screen.

You should call the following lines at the start of your render method:

```
// This is black, you can choose any color, technically one call is enough
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 1f);
// This line clears the screen (more precisely the color buffer, there are others but this one should be fine)
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Now, since it looks like you only want to generate them randomly once create them once in your initialization method (like the create method) and save them in an array/Collection:

```
// Global field
Array<Vector2> circlePositions = new Array<>();

// initialization method
renderer = new ShapeRenderer();

Random rand = new RandomXS128();
for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
{
    circlePositions.add(
            new Vector2(
                    rand.nextInt(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()),
                    rand.nextInt(Gdx.graphics.getHeight())));
    circlePositions.add(
            new Vector2(
                    rand.nextInt(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()),
                    rand.nextInt(Gdx.graphics.getHeight())));
}
```

Then in your render method you can draw your circles like this:

```
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 1);
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

renderer.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
for (int i = 0; i < circlePositions.size; i++)
{
    Vector2 pos = circlePositions.get(i);

    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
        renderer.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        renderer.circle(pos.x, pos.y, 5);
    } else
    {
        renderer.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        renderer.circle(pos.x, pos.y, 3);
    }
}
renderer.end();
```

If you don't want to redraw everything at e.g. 60 fps, then take a look at non continues rendering.

Comment: Thank you, It was really helpful